# Cast to GetType a object

Tags: c#, types, casting

Is there any way where i can cast a object to *GetType()* a  object value?

such as:

```
object result = method.Invoke(instance, parametersValue); //method returnt int
```

i want result cast to int Dynamically.

Comment: While you are looking for a solution, let me remind you, that even if you have one, there will be no way for you to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to convert an object to its type with the `Type` object.

What you can do is use `dynamic` keyword and it will resolve the type in runtime.

```
dynamic result = method.Invoke(instance, parametersValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the question, GetType() is not an object, is a method.

You can execute the sentence you wrote just as is it. To cast result back to int use:

```
int intVar = (int) result;
```